# asmx web service returning xml instead of json in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, web-services, json, jquery, asp.net-4.0

i have just upgraded a test copy of my site to asp.net 4.0 and have noticed a strange issue that only arises when i upload the site to my server.

the site has an asmx web service that returns json, yet when i run the site on my server it returns xml.  it as been working fine in asp.net 3.5 for over a year.

the webMethod is decorated with the correct attributes...

```
[WebMethod][ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<LocationRecentChange> RecentChanges()
```

and on my local machine it returns json.

yet on the server (Windows 2008 64bit) it returns xml.

using firebug console you will see a 200 OK response and a bunch of XML, and on my local machine the data returned is the JSON i expect.

Here is the javascript that calls the service..

```
function loadRecentData() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "service/spots.asmx/RecentChanges",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: loadRecentUpdates,
    failure: function(msg) {
        //alert(msg);
    }
});
```

}

Any suggestions welcome, this has got me stumped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure .NET 4 is installed on your server?

The ScriptHandlerFactory's "type" string in .NET 4 is:

```
System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

ASP.NET 4 now includes that in its default web.config at the machine level.  So, you shouldn't need any mapping to the ScriptHandlerFactory in your project's web.config, 3.5 or 4.

Comment: Turns out the server has something funky going on with IIS.  I cannot recreate the issue locally, but inserting the item into the web.config does fix it.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Can you edit the answer to include the exact code I need to add to my web.config (including which section it needs to be added to)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

well i managed to track it down by reading up about ajax web services requests are handled here...

http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/ajax/tutorial-05-cs.aspx

basically a handler from asp.net 3.5 needs to be declared in your web.config handlers section under system.webserver so that it can return a JSON response instead of the default.

here is what you need to add to the web.config [handlers section](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/handlers) (also add to [httpHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) section if you need to support IIS6)...

```
<handlers>
   <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

i have my suspicions that this will need replacing with a .net 4.0 version of the same handler, but for now, it works.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Can you edit the answer to include the include which section it needs to be added to? And any additional elements such as <remove> if required. Thanks.

Comment: have updated it for you and added links to relevant section documentation

Comment: But you haven't said where to add the <handlers> section... Where does that go? Where ever I put it, I get an error.

Comment: It goes in the system.webServer section of the web.config