# Standard Web Services (.asmx) no longer supported in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: web-services, .net-4.0

Are the standard web services(.asmx) no longer supported with asp.net 4.0 ... I am using 4.0 but i dont really need all the complications with WCF...should i use old standard web services or WCF for some pretty simple web services?

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

[asmx web service returning xml instead of json in .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749954/asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json-in-net-4-0)