# get JSON from ASP.NET web service ASMX file

Tags: asp.net, xml, json, web-services

I'm creating a web service using ASP.NET, C#, currently it is giving XML, but I'm going to get JSON, this is how I create my webmtheod:

```
[Webservice(Namespace="http://myurl)]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfiles_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

[WebMehod]
public string myfunction()
{

string r = "......";


return r;
}
```

these are in an ASMX file, which I call it in my browser

Comment: this function returns me XML output but I'm going to get JSON, how can I get JSON? I think I should use .NET serialization functions, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return JSON from your method you will need to use the ScriptMethod attribute.

Structure your method like this, notice the `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute.

```
    [WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string MyMethod()
    {

    }
```

At the moment, this method is returning a `string`, which can be a `JSON` structured string. However, you may be better to return an object, which can be parsed as `JSON`. `List<string>` as well as Class's with standard data-types, like `integers`, `strings` etc are great for this. You can then return just that object. the `ScriptMethod` takes care of transforming it into `JSON`.

For example:

The Class you want to return:

```
      public class MyJson
      {
         public int ID;
         public List<string> SomeList;
         public string SomeText;
     }
```

And your method to return a populated `MyJson`

```
        [WebMethod()]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public MyJson MyMethod()
        { 
          MyJson m = new MyJson();
          m.ID = 1;
          m.SomeText = "Hello World!";
          m.SomeList = new List<string>();
          m.SomeList.Add("Foo");
          m.SomeList.Add("Bar");

          return m;
        }
```

The return `JSON` will be structured just like the class. The property names will be used too, and your `List<string>` will become an array

Call this using AJAX. JQuery in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/YourPage.aspx/MyMethod",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

             // content will be in here... I.E
             var id = msg.d.ID;
             var st = msg.d.SomeText;
             var sl = msg.d.SomeList;
             var i = sl.length;
            var firstSlItem = sl[0];
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but it seems that I'm still getting an XML (it is now structured like my class), how should I call my webservice in my browser to get json output?

Comment: Call it with AJAX, making sure to specify the Datatype as JSON. I will add some example code.

Comment: If it's still returning AJAX then see this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749954/asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json-in-net-4-0 - don't forget to mark all as answered if they help, and upvote other answers if they help you too.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach would be to use `JavaScriptSerializer` to return JSON as a string:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public string GetItems() {
    List<string> listOfItems = new List<string> {"asdf", "qwerty", "abc", "123"};

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = js.Serialize(listOfItems);

    return json;
}
```

...be sure to use this import:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

...and you will then have to parse the result in javascript / jQuery like this:

```
var result = "";

$.ajax({

      // ...other properties defined here...

      success: function (response) {
            result = JSON.parse(response.d);
      }
});

// the List<string> has been parsed into an array:
for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
      alert(result[i]);
}
```

If you convert an instance of a class in this same way, such as @Darren's example here, it will then be parsed as a javascript object-literal.

*Also note that in an `.asmx` file webmethods are declared as public instance methods, as opposed to `public static` in `.aspx` files.*